# Why is page rank so high for a teacher's personal site

Tags: seo, pagerank

I have several sites with google page rank 0.

- These sites have unique content (in my native language).
- They have sites on google+ and facebook with at least 50 likes.
- They are registered in many search engines.
- There are quite many links (not fewer than hundred) pointing to them - site openlinkprofiler.org gave to the majority of these links low values (about 5%), but this is better than nothing.
- There aren't links from "bas seo" pages to my sites
- I am commenting in relevant sites using links to my pages.
- All these pages receive high or satisfactory rankings in automatic SEO analysis tools.
- There aren't many unique users who vist these pages per day, but also this number is not a zero

But still pagerank zero for months.

And another example, a teacher of calculus from our faculty (which has about 1500 students and he teaches about 150 unique students in a year) has a personal site with page rank 3 (called krbalek.cz)

- His site is not valid according to w3c
- He has not connections with social networks
- System openlinkprofiler.org tells that there are only a few links pointing to the page
- He probably does not do any seo and Seo analysers do not give the best results for him

Is there any general advice for me, what am I doing wrong? The only thing that came to my mind is that his personal site has been in service for about 10 year and all my sites aren't older than a year.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PageRank is a formula driven by links and links alone. Anything you mentioned that is not to do with links is irrelevant. PageRank has to come initially from external links pointing to your website. The pages that these links are on also need to have PageRank in order for it to flow to your website and the links need to be followable (not contain the `nofollow` link relationship).

The real value of PageRank does not really coincide with the visible digit you see - think of it measured on a scale of 0 to 1. Your site will likely have a PageRank score, but not yet at 0.10 hence why it would show 0 still. PageRank is also only updated periodically, maybe 3 or 4 times per year.

I'd also advise not to worry about PageRank - it's an almost meaningless metric unless you fully understand how it works.

Comment: So if you want for example to insert adds to your website, then the most significant factor for the price of these adds is simply the traffic, no one looks to page rank. Am I right?

Comment: Well. No. Clueless fools that don't know any better will chase PageRank all day long. What they pay for an ad on a website will be determined by PageRank. That doesn't make it correct or effective but that's what a lot of people will always do.